# Python ctypes's sprintf formats any float type as b'0.000000' or b'5.25662e-315'

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm experimenting with the fastest way to format a float as a string with as minimal representation as possible (no trailing 0's, no decimal places if it can be helped, no scientific notation). I've decided to try Python's `ctypes` module.

Based on several examples I thought this function would work, but instead it always prints `b'0.000000'` if using `%f` or `b'5.25124e-315'` if using `%g`
Code:

```
from ctypes import *
import msvcrt
def floatToStr3(n:float)->str:
    libc = cdll.msvcrt
    print("n in:", n)
    sb = create_string_buffer(100)
    libc.sprintf(sb, b"%g", c_float(n))
    print("sb out:", sb.value)
    return sb.value

import random
floatToStr3(random.random())
floatToStr3(random.random())
floatToStr3(random.random())
floatToStr3(random.random())
floatToStr3(random.random())
floatToStr3(random.random())
```

Output:

```
n in: 0.9164215022054657
sb out: b'5.25662e-315'
n in: 0.6366531536720886
sb out: b'5.23343e-315'
n in: 0.07371310207853521
sb out: b'5.1052e-315'
n in: 0.6353450576077702
sb out: b'5.23332e-315'
n in: 0.2839487624658935
sb out: b'5.18628e-315'
n in: 0.5540225836869241
sb out: b'5.22658e-315'
```

I have a strong feeling I'm just not using create_string_buffer correctly, but I don't know what the answer is. Formatting using ints works.

Using Python 3.7.4 on Windows 10.

Comment: Check c_double this works for me `libc.sprintf(sb, b"%.16f", c_double(n))`, as in your case c_float only returns 0.00000. I'm doing this on Linux.

Comment: Yes that worked. If you'd like to make this an answer I'll accept it. It doesn't appear to be faster than f-strings, but maybe I can play with it more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Observations**:

- Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)
- Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) when working with *CTypes* functions
- [[Python.Docs]: Built-in Types - Numeric Types - int, float, complex](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) states (**emphasis** is mine):

  > Floating point numbers are usually implemented using **`double` in C**

  By casting the number to *ctypes.c_float*, **it loses precision** (as typically *float* is 4 bytes long, while *double* is 8), yielding values very close to ***0***, and hence the output (also intuited by @frost-nzcr4)
- Calling *sprintf* directly, is definitely faster than calling any other *Python* conversion function. But let's not forget that *Python* has many optimizations, so even if the function call by itself is faster, the overhead needed for that call to be possible (*Python* <=>*C* conversions), could be higher and in some cases the overall performance worse than using a *Python* solution
- If we talk about speed, placing `sb = create_string_buffer(100)` (and others) **inside the function** is not very smart. Do it outside (once, at the beginning) and only make use of it in the function

Below it's an example.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import random
import sys
import timeit


c_float = cts.c_float
c_double = cts.c_double
cdll = cts.cdll
create_string_buffer = cts.create_string_buffer

swprintf = cts.windll.msvcrt.swprintf
swprintf.argtypes = (cts.c_wchar_p, cts.c_wchar_p, cts.c_double)  # !!! swprintf (and all the family functions) have varargs !!!
swprintf.restype = cts.c_int

buf = cts.create_unicode_buffer(100)


def original(f: float) -> str:
    libc_ = cdll.msvcrt
    #print("n in:", f)
    sb = create_string_buffer(100)
    libc_.sprintf(sb, b"%g", c_double(f))
    #print("sb out:", sb.value)
    return sb.value.decode()


def improved(f: float) -> str:
    swprintf(buf, "%g", f)
    return buf.value


def percent(f: float) -> str:
    return "%g" % f


def format_(f: float) -> str:
    return "{0:g}".format(f)


def f_string_default(f: float) -> str:
    return f"{f}"

def f_string_g(f: float) -> str:
    return f"{f:g}"


number_count = 3
numbers = [random.random() for _ in range(number_count)]
number = numbers[0]


def main(*argv):
    funcs = (
        original,
        improved,
        percent,
        format_,
        f_string_default,
        f_string_g,
    )

    print("Functional tests")
    for f in numbers:
        print("\nNumber (default format): {0:}".format(f))
        for func in funcs:
            print("    {0:s}: {1:}".format(func.__name__, func(f)))

    print("\nPerformance tests (time took by each function)")
    for func in funcs:
        t = timeit.timeit(stmt="func(number)", setup="from __main__ import number, {0:s} as func".format(func.__name__))
        print("    {0:s}: {1:}".format(func.__name__, t))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q061231308]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Functional tests
>
> Number (default format): 0.09201480511926563
>     original: 0.0920148
>     improved: 0.0920148
>     percent: 0.0920148
>     format_: 0.0920148
>     f_string_default: 0.09201480511926563
>     f_string_g: 0.0920148
>
> Number (default format): 0.3778731171686579
>     original: 0.377873
>     improved: 0.377873
>     percent: 0.377873
>     format_: 0.377873
>     f_string_default: 0.3778731171686579
>     f_string_g: 0.377873
>
> Number (default format): 0.8507691869686248
>     original: 0.850769
>     improved: 0.850769
>     percent: 0.850769
>     format_: 0.850769
>     f_string_default: 0.8507691869686248
>     f_string_g: 0.850769
>
> Performance tests (time took by each function)
>     original: 1.7038035999999999
>     improved: 1.4332302
>     percent: 0.25398619999999994
>     format_: 0.37500920000000004
>     f_string_default: 0.9683423999999996
>     f_string_g: 0.33258160000000014
>
> Done.
> ```

As seen, builtin *Python* alternatives perform way better than *CTypes* ones. What I find curious (wondering if I didn't do something wrong), is that **the *f-string* variant is much lower** (performance-wise) than what I expected it to be (just when using default specifier - things are "a bit" different when using ***:g*** - thanks @pankaj for the tip!).
It might be interesting reading [[Python]: Python Patterns - An Optimization Anecdote](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str).

Comment: My testing is also showing that ctypes is slower. Wow, what a response. Thank you!

Comment: You f-string numbers are slower because you are using different format specifier (default specified instead of 'g' format specified: If you change it to
```return f"{f:g}"```
then the results are much better.

Comment: Thank you @pankaj! Incorporated that piece of info in the answer.